# Action camera connected via two usb extenders and RJ45 doesnt work?

Tags: action-cam, usb

I started using my Action camera as Webcam via USB - works good. I wanted longer cable so googled a bit how to extend USB cable and found solution two USB extenders via RJ45 cable.

Computer <--> usb 2.0 to RJ45 <--> RJ45 UTP cable <--> RJ45 to micro USB <--> action camera

The problem is, camera is not turning on - basically I bought extenders which are converting RJ45 to USB (and micro usb on the other side).
Question is how to make it happen ? Invert signal or something is possible ? Camera is dead and extenders are not showing any traffic on led lights.

**More details**

USB 2.0 port on motherboard has not been modified. Both USB to RJ45 are working - tested when plugging in etrhent cable to usb. To give you more information, here are the models I am using - so from motherboard USB is going Edimax EU-4208 which is connected to RJ45 cable, that cable (1m) is going to ICY BOX IB-AC510 and from this, its going via microusb to action camera Eken H9. I am very afraid that this will not work as they are only converters or is there any hope ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Hope you get it working. We could use some more info. What have you tried? Have you used that camera with a USB **2.0** port successfully before? Is the camera battery/wall-powered, or does it use USB power? If USB, do the adapters pass the full 500 mA? Have you used the USB-Ethernet converter pairs successfully with other devices? RJ-45 is a connector; (read the insulation) what category is the cable? What length? Are the USB-Eth converters active devices, or just "converters"… abusing ethernet's 8 wires as USB leads? What makes and models are each of the involved components?

Comment: Hi @JoelReid, thanks for asking more info - here are they - USB 2.0 port on motherboard has not been modified. Both USB to RJ45 are working - tested when plugging in etrhent cable to usb. To give you more information, here are the models I am using - so from motherboard USB is going Edimax EU-4208 which is connected to RJ45 cable, that cable (1m) is going to ICY BOX IB-AC510 and from this, its going via microusb to action camera Eken H9. I am very afraid that this will not work as they are only converters or is there any hope ? Thanks Joel.

Comment: Given your answers, that's important info! Just a note on StackExchange norms; consider revising your question to include additional info. Everything important goes in the questions and answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, given the models you mentioned in comments, the purpose of both of your ethernet adapters is to connect usb host devices, like computers, to ethernet network devices, like switches and routers.

There do exist purpose-built USB extenders (see: [example NewEgg search](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=usb%20cat5%20extension&Submit=ENE)), some of which have RJ-45 ports to operate over cat5 or cat6 cables just for availability and cost savings—but sadly, that's not what you have. They're also usually considerably more expensive. And they do not work with ethernet data networks, instead only as a matched pair. I'm afraid you'll need to work up another solution.

Comment: yeah I though that, thanks a lot